How can I use a dynamic key for getting the error in a Laravel Livewire form?
I want to get an error message using a Livewire form inside of foreach with a dynamic key like this:
<x-input-error class="mt-2" :messages="$errors->get('form.productData.product_variants.{{ $index }}.name')" />

But the message won’t show if there is any error from the form.productData.product_variants.0.name rules that I set.
When I access the error message using static key like this,
<x-input-error class="mt-2" :messages="$errors->get('form.productData.product_variants.0.name')" />

The error message is shown.
How can I achieve to get error messages using a dynamic key from $index inside of my foreach looping?
